# splitting string list when eqal item is found on condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to splitting the list when specific item found. So I can do with that using array if it is list of integers without any problem but want to do the same thing with list of stirings.
Here is how I do that with a list of intergers(in here I take '5' as my specific number)

```
num_list =[0,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5]
 
arrays = [[num_list[0]]] # array of sub-arrays (starts with first value)
 
for i in range(1, len(num_list)): # go through each element after the first
    if num_list[i] != 5: # If it's larger than the previous
        arrays[len(arrays)-1].append(num_list[i]) # Add it to the last sub-array
    else: # otherwise
        arrays.append([num_list[i]]) # Make a new sub-array 
print(arrays)
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4], [5]]
```

I want to do this same thing with list of strings.

Comment: add the string example for reference

Comment: @Sabil ex: if add in num_list as `num_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry","apple","pine_apple"]` I want output like [["apple","banana","cherry"],["apple","pine_apple"]]

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: @Sabil I want to split that list into lists where apple found ex: we have `num_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry","apple","pine_apple"] `  I want this list split into this `[["apple","banana","cherry"],["apple","pine_apple"]]` . (broke the list where can find apple)

Comment: what will  be your output for `['apple'. 'apple', 'apple','apple'. 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'. 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'. 'apple', 'apple']`

Comment: Check my answer, your code works perfectly as it expected. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is just to walk through the list, 'resetting' each time you hit the special string:

```
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple', 'pine_apple']

out = []
y = []    
for i in my_list:
    if y and i == "apple":
        out.append(y)
        y = []
    y.append(i)

out.append(y)

print(out)
# [['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'], ['apple', 'pine_apple']]

# Or with different input:
# my_list = ['a', 'b', 'apple', 'c', 'd', 'apple', 'apple', 'e']
# [['a', 'b'], ['apple', 'c', 'd'], ['apple'], ['apple', 'e']]
```